# Are these bricks with dimple on top of a stud LEGO?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

These bricks came in a lot of LEGO bricks from the 1960's-1970's.
I have looked on Google to check other manufacturers and I couldn't find a match to them.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I think these bricks are [Lino Method](http://www.architoys.net/toys/toylist1.html)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes you are right.thanks again